# CRUD table - should Edit be engaged in gridview or detail view?

Tags: tables, data-tables, crud

Let's say a gridview is being created. Each row shows a few high-level items, but there is more information in a detail view.

Which is a more appropriate pattern for a user who wishes to see all details, and optionally edit them?

---

**Option A: View Detail action in gridview, edit mode in detail view**

[image: A table with View Details as the action on each row]

[image: A detail view with an edit button]

Pros: Shows all information before engaging in an edit mode, which might be expected by the user

Cons: Always requires an extra click for users who know they want to edit

---

**Option B: Provide direct access to editing from the grid view**

[image: A table with Edit as the action on each row]

[image: A detail view that is ready to edit each field]

Pros: Saves a click, all information is still viewable

Cons: "Edit" doesn't imply there is more information in a detail view. Is it weird for a user to be able to edit information they haven't seen yet (the Other Information section)?

---

**Option C: Show both View and Edit options on the gridview**

This seems kind of redundant, because Option A would take care of both cases.

---

I'm leaning toward sending the users directly into Edit mode, but would that create any confusion or hindrances with a heavy detail view?

Comment: Option C is not redundant, it adds affordance. A user has to know what each record has to offer: More details and an option to edit. See my edited answer, as it is all about adapting to the user's needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you provide both? You might want to shorten "View details" into just "view", "more" or "details":

[image]

"EDIT" shows the modal in edit mode, "DETAILS" shows the modal in view mode with the edit button present, just like in your examples.

Having two links and a same modal with a view and edit mode is not redundant, it adds affordance. A user has to know what each record has to offer: More details and an option to edit.

**Adapt to the path the user takes**

1. Is a user curious what more information there is, then show a readable view of the information. Does that user want to edit from there, provide a button to edit.
2. Is a user directly interested in editing the information in the table, then allow to open that view in an editable mode.

So your ideas A and B are good, you just have to combine them.

Comment: I'm struggling a little with the user looking at the details and then wanting to enter an edit state from there... which is option 1.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

If the text choice in the cell implies confusion regarding the action involved, remove the text and put an icon for each action

[image]

### Option 2

Add interactivity

- Hovering : show the details and replace "View details" by "Edit"
- Clicking : edit the content

[image]

Comment: I wanted to add an example with icons too, but found the magnifier icon look too much like a search action. I like the idea in option 2! Only does it still hide the edit ability in grid view.

Comment: Can be a magnifier or an eye, I just put the one it looks better   About the text, maybe *View/Edit*.

Comment: I like option 2 as well, but let's say there are 20 more pieces of information to view/edit - I think the sheet is still our best bet for that, to allow scrolling.

Comment: For 20 or more pieces to change I don't think a modal pop up is a good choice. Actually modals with a long info (or form) is the opposite of a good UX  

Comment: It's likely a big sheet, not a small modal dialog, but I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

I made some assumptions about what you described.

Assumptions n1:
User#A has a basic IT education.
User#B is a millennial.

Assumption n2:
User doesn´t need to update this information quite often.

Answer: I will prioritize the "view details" as label for the button instead of "edit".

Maybe I am wrong; if you provide more context, it could help find a better answer :)

Assumptions n3:
every user can use a keyboard and mouse as input devices.

Modal box:
The update button is disabled from default because the user needs at least to edit a field successfully.

Editing feature
Path#1. Click on the edit button, and the first field will be on focus. The user can confirm by clicking on the key Enter.
Path#2. Double-click the mouse on the field to edit. The user can confirm by clicking on the key Enter.

I am attaching the short prototype.

Having two paths for the same feature could be confusing, but you can have a quick usability test to understand the best solution for your user. ;)

I attached a lo-fi prototype. I hope it will help you to understand my explanation.[image]

May my answer support you to find the solution or inspiration.
Cheers.

Comment: This is how I was thinking my Option A would work. Sounds like a vote for it!